# Proper design of class hierarchy

Tags: c#, class, design-patterns, hierarchy

I'm trying to design a class hierarchy in C# to properly model my application model.
The problem is I'm not sure which is the right way to do it.

Let's say I have an Order class which is supposed to be the base (abstract) class for all order types and the reference type I'm working with when using orders. The order class has only a single 'important' method: let's call it order.PlaceOrder(), but there are multiple (orthogonal) requirements that an order might have to do (or not do): log the placing of the order, place the order asynchronously (PlaceOrder method returns immediately) and others.

Now, I want to make actual concrete classes which can support any number of these requirements. For example:
    class GoogleOrder : LoggedOrder, AsyncOrder, etc
    class AppleOrder: AsyncOrder
    class MicrosoftOrder : Order

The question is: if I want to create such a class by deriving from all the "strategies", then they all (but one) have to be interfaces, whereas I wish to inherit actual implementation and avoid copy/pasting of code, and I'm not sure how to do it.

I come from a C++ background, where I could just derive from multiple base classes (or possibly use a policy based design, like Andrei Alexandrescu describes in his book), but in C# I'm not sure how to do it, even though this seems like a very general question, one which I should know by now.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: This question is more suitable to programmers - http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You probably want to use [composition over inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)

Comment: Or maybe you should separate the actual "Actions" on orders in separate class hierarchy. For example you'll have base class "OrderProcessor" and then derived classes "AsyncOrderProcessor" and "OrderLogger".

Comment: For something simple, like the logging strategy, it's easy to pass in a Logger interface in the constructor (even an empty one) and use that to log, but for other things, like execute async, I don't see it ...

Comment: The questions seems unclear to me.  You can't put all your methods in the base and call them from the derived as needed?  I am not even sure you've explained why you need to derive.

Comment: @Yevgeniy.Chernobrivets That sounds promising, but what if I wish to do Logging and Async processing on the same order. I think I would need a list of processors in the Order class (which doesn't sound too clean) ?

Comment: @user1646737 That would definitely work, but it would mean I would have to have all implementation in the base class, then derive and use only some of it. I just wish to separate it as much as possible. Doesn't have to be thru inheritance, but somehow.

Comment: You can actually try to implement it this way: create specific implementation of Processor class and pass to it Process method Order object. So you can create different processors one by one and run them on same order. Or you can create order property called "Processors" which will have list of available processors and then when you call "PlaceOrder" on order object you call all processors from list.

Comment: Why is it inferior to have all your methods in the base?  The purpose of object-oriented programming is to put them there, whether you need them every time or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like your design calls for "Decorator pattern", Decorator pattern gives flexibility to add responsibilities/roles dynamically and with different combinations however you like instead of using inheritance.

here are example on how to implement decorator:

http://alagesann.com/2013/08/16/decorator-pattern-made-easy/
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern

hope that helps.

here is the sample code for your scenario. see if it helps.

```
 public abstract class Order
    {
        public abstract void PlaceOrder(); // log the placeing of the ordr, place the order asynchronously
    }
    public class MicrosoftOrder : Order // default order
    {
        public void PlaceOrder()
        {
            // default implementation for placing order.
        }
    }
    public class AppleOrder : Order // for asycn functionalities.
    {
        private Order order;
        public AppleOrder(Order order)
        {
            this.order = order;
        }
        public void PlaceOrder()
        {
            // Implement async functionalities.
            // you can also call default order as
            // order.PlaceOrder();
        }
    }
    public class GoogleOrder : Order // logged order
    {
        private Order order;
        public GoogleOrder(Order order)
        {
            this.order = order;
        }
        public void PlaceOrder()
        {           
            // Implement logged order
            // you can also call default order as
            // order.PlaceOrder();
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Order order = new MicrosoftOrder();
            order.PlaceOrder(); // Default Order;
            Order orderWithAsync = new AppleOrder(order);
            orderWithAsync.PlaceOrder(); // Place order with asycn 

            Order orderWithAsyncAndlogging = new GoogleOrder(orderWithAsync);
            orderWithAsyncAndlogging.PlaceOrder(); // order with asynch and logging.            
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hmm, from the description on wikipedia, this sounds like it's exactly what I'm looking for. I need to investigate a bit more tho.

Comment: I think this is what I'm looking for. However, let's say that I'm in method where I need to create and process a Google order only.

Comment: Perhaps for this example, the three decorators should be renamed to reflect their specific behavior, and usage should be like this:     Order googleOrder = new LoggedOrder(new AsyncOrder(new SimpleOrder())); // and other types of order similarly created ... also, I'm thinking if there is any prettier way for instantiating an order. Maybe chaining a SetBehavior method (which returns a reference to 'this')

Comment: What do you guys think? Also, I will be accepting this answer soon, as it does solve my problem.

Comment: @user2190351 to simplify the creation of an order and a bunch of decorators, you could take a look at the Builder pattern. With it, creation of an order would look something like: `Order order = orderBuilder.Async().Logged().GetOrder();`